# Hide teamsite-link in Sharepoint Quick-Launch when no permission to teamsite

Tags: quick-launch, team-sites, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-permissions

When creating subsites in Sharepoint, the subsite-url will only be visible in the Quick Launch if you have permission to see this subsite.

We would now like to start using Teams and we want to replace the subsites by teamsites. We manually create an url in the Quick Launch of the 'main' site to the teamsite, but this url is also visible to users who do not have access to the teamsite.

How can we configure the url to the teamsites to only be visible to those users who have access to the teamsites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you creating manually links, there are no security trimming for them. Unfortunately I think there is no simply option how to achieve what you want.

You can use on links audiences, but there you should have audience for each Team Site.
Or you can create CUstom WebPart where will be checked permissions on all displayed Team Site Addresses and hide these, where he won't have permissions.

Comment: I have enabled the "audiences" options and I created links for each Team Site, this worked well enough for me. Thank you for the reply!